# Paypal Reports of Payments by Hour of the Day

Tags: sql, paypal, report

Is there a way to download Paypal Transactions into csv and use some reporting tool (Excel, or online) to do out of box reporting on it?
The one I am looking for at the moment is report of Payments that came in, by hour of the day for the data. I want to know which hours most of my orders come in.

Update July 9, 2017:
Here is the image of how the data looks like in the standard Paypal Activity download. If I upload this to Access/MySQL or just use Excel, wat SQL do I use to  get a report of orders by hour of the day? For example, I would like to know if I get most orders between 7:00 and 8:00 AM, etc.
[image: view]

Comment: We do more of programming here.

Comment: Thank you - I upload an image of the data, and am looking for the SQL for the report.